# REGEX help required - breaking up line

Tags: java, regex

`(city  = 'pune' AND country = 'india') OR (division  = 'it') AND (resource  = 'someresource' )`

I want to break this into groups depending on brackets.

Group 1 - `(city  = 'pune' AND country = 'india')`
Group 2 - `(division  = 'it')`
Group 3 - `(resource  = 'someresource' )`

Can somebody please provide the regular expression for the example in Java?

Comment: There is not only one flavour of regular expressions; you need to provide context (use tags, too). What have you tried (see the FAQ)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this one :** (Demo : http://regexr.com?33u8e)

```
(\(.+?\))
```

**Code Example (in PHP) :**

```
<?php
     $subject = "(city = 'pune' AND country = 'india') OR (division = 'it') AND (resource = 'someresource' )";
     $pattern = '/(\(.+?\))/';
     preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
     print_r($matches);
?>
```

---

Another approach : *try splitting (using positive look-behind)*

```
(?<=\))\s
```

---

**EDIT: Final answer (in Java)**

```
String[] parts = str.split("(?<=\\))\\s");
```

Comment: It just returns the entire string. I want it to be broken.

Comment: 'Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\(.+?\\))");
        String string = "(city = 'pune' AND country = 'india') OR (division = 'it') AND (resource = 'someresource' )";
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            System.out.println("Total matches: " + matcher.groupCount());
            for(int i=0, max=matcher.groupCount(); i<max; i++ ) {
                System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No match");
        }'

Comment: Total matches: 1
(city = 'pune' AND country = 'india') OR (division = 'it') AND (resource = 'someresource' )

Comment: @SudhanshuUmalkar Well, I suppose that's Java, right? Then I suppose I can't help you with the syntax. However, why don't you try my last edit?

Comment: @SudhanshuUmalkar Try `String[] parts = str.split("(?<=\\))\\s");`

Comment: @SudhanshuUmalkar Glad that worked, mate! (And imagine I haven't touched Java for like 5 years... lol). If this answer was helpful, please don't forget to mark it as an answer so that others may be helped too. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: `\((.+?)\)`

```
string mystring = "(city = 'pune' AND country = 'india') OR (division = 'it') AND (resource = 'someresource' )";
Match results = Regex.Match(mystring, @"\((.+?)\)",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

foreach (Group g in results.Groups)
{
    string token = g.Value;
}
```

### [Live Demo](http://regexr.com?33u8h)

Comment: No luck, it just returns the entire string when I try out this thing in Java.

Comment: You hadn't mentioned about your language.

Comment: Sorry about that but I guess that REGEX would be common across all languages.